# Send contents of jsp page as an email Using Java - without servlet programming

Tags: java, jsp, collections, jstl

I have an application to send the sql query results as an email.
I know how to send static contents of a jsp page in mail using javamail.
But i need to include my query results to the jsp page.

I have a jsp page "email.jsp"

In My java class i have fetched the records. I need to set the values in

```
List<DBValues> values = getRowsFromDB();
```

I need to iterate this list using jstl in my jsp page and then send the jsp page.

Could someone help me on this.
Please ask me if question is not clear.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by send the jsp page ? Page content ?

Comment: Why can't you use a servlet? And what do you mean with *I know how to send static contents of a jsp page in mail using javamail*, how you do this?

Comment: to sent contents of a jsp page i can read the contents using {code}File f = new File("myfile.jsp"); String s = FileUtils.readFileToString(f.getName()); msg.setContent(s); transport.send(s); {code}

Comment: i need to use the list values in the jsp page and then read the file and send it with my required values

Comment: So what you really send is the content of **the JSP file**, not of the generated HTML...

Comment: yes can you help me with my problem

Comment: looks like rocket science to me :)